# SQL Server Vs MongoDB : Speed test?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, performance, mongodb

MongoDB:

```
var x = nosql.GetRecords<Event>(p => p._Data == "rawhix", 0, 12222);
// ICursor<T> GetRecords<T>(expression, skip, limit);
```

SQL:

```
SqlDataReader dr = SqlHelper.ExecuteReader("Select Top(12222)* From NewsFeed WHERE _Data = 'dddd'");
```

the MongoDB contains 1000000 record which are the same in the SQL . 
 
the data stored as the following:

```
Id = 1 , _Data = 1abc
Id = 2 , _Data = 2bc 
... etc
```

`Event` class  :

```
Class Event => int Id => string _Data
```

when I run the code the result is: 

 Mongo : 580ms 
SQL : 102ms 

Should I do anything to fix this !! because the mongo was always faster except this test !?!

Comment: Why do you think that MongoDB would be faster than SQL Server for this type of simple query? Assuming you have an appropriate index on the _Data column I'd expect any relational database to be lightning quick at this type of query. Seriously - this type of benchmark proves nothing.

Comment: Is this a repost? Also, yesterday your results were "Mongo : 172ms 
SQL : 185ms ." - isn't this the same question? so what changed?

Comment: here I've tried to seek for a non existed result !!

Comment: You could leave the SQL part out of this question and it would still work fine - 580ms for a simple query means you need an index.

Comment: You have a flawed assumption that MongoDB is some *next generation* thing that will blow all flavors of SQL servers out of the water. It's not, it's just a tool that performs a similar, albeit a different role from a SQL server. So, these kind of test are meaningless, they're like asking is Sébastien Loeb faster than Fernando Alonso.

Comment: is Sébastien Loeb faster than Fernando Alonso !!! HHH

Comment: Also: Speed for a single query is almost pointless of a benchmark.  The appropriate thing to check for would be how each deals with concurrency, since that's more often the limiting factor (and what will make or break an application).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need an index. Run this in the mongo console:

```
db.Events.ensureIndex({_Data:1});
```

or you can call it through the C# driver:

```
MongoDatabase db = server.GetDatabase("your_db_name");
MongoCollection<Event> events = hr.GetCollection<Event>("events");
employees.EnsureIndex("_Data");
```

You wouldn't want to do this on every call though since it is another call to the DB and will have a very tiny performance hit.

Comment: yes this is in the mongo console, but what about the c# driver !!

Comment: Added how to do it through the C# driver - although you only need to do this once per database so I wouldn't call it every time.

Comment: @Rawhi: so what were your stats after ensureIndex() ?